# Как программно принудительно вызвать событие в javascript внутри которого тоже javascript

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток, вот протестил этот код,

```js
  window.onload = function() { /* ваш код */ };
```

но, что то он не все события запускает, есть что то похожее и постабильней в работе? Я с javascript только еще учусь работать. Чтобы принудительно запустить команду в javascript.

Comment: Не понятно в чем проблема, объясните подробнее

Answer (score 0):

window.onload код будет запущен когда страница будет полностью загружена, включая все фреймы, объекты и изображения. Это будет работать во всех случаях, но скорее всего не самое кроссбраузерное.

Comment: вот например <script> window.onload = function() { <script src="//f="text/javascript" async></script> };

Comment: Это так не работает. О_О. Внутри функции JS вы пытаетесь выполнить HTML код. Это бред. Вам тогда нужно посмотреть на подключение JS файлов через JS. А не посредством HTML.

Comment: можно подробней как это сделать в качестве примера? не, это не совсем html, я пытаюсь в теле одного скрипта, запустить другой скрипт, это не моя идея, это я увидел один из советов одного программиста, вот попытался это проверить на практике

Comment: window.onload = function() { 
  var t = 'Hello, World!';
  alert(t);
}

Comment: Интересное окно вылезло, а как кликнуть по Hello, World!  Нажать Ok. или закрыть это событие через рандомное время, в продолжение это кода window.onload = function() { var t = 'Hello, World!'; alert(t); , что там прописать дальше команду клик и кнопку?

Comment: Shmasya, какой класс у этой кнопки? что то когда она всплывает, я не могу посмотреть исходники кодов в браузере

Comment: Советую вам начать всё с самого начала. Прям с самого. Возможно программирование не для вас.

Comment: _я увидел один из советов одного программиста_-хотелось бы источник

Answer (score 0):

самовызывающаяся функция

```
(function(){
ваш код
}())
```

Comment: спасибо, это тоже попробую